# JavaScript xml object, access node problem

Tags: javascript, xml

Hi am trying to get sun rise and sun set from the xml object. I am able to get country and output it to the html page but when I try to get sun or even coord it just shows as undefined. I realize I cannot get textContent because they have none, they have values right?

Xml data using http request. I output this to the console so I can see what I am getting in return.

```
 <current>
     <city id="2343" name="Edmonton">
      <cooord lon="444" lat="54">
      </coord>
      <country>CA</country>
      <sun rise="2020-03-01t02:07:33" set="2020-03-01t07:33"></sun
     </city>
    </current>
```

JavaScript Only

```
function loadWeather(e){
  if (xmlhttp_weather.status == 200) {

    weatherXML = xmlhttp_weather.responseXML;
    weatherCount = weatherXML.getElementsByTagName("city");
    console.log(weatherXML);
    let weatherList = weatherCount[0].getElementsByTagName("sun");
    console.log(weatherList[0].attributes);


    console.log(weatherCount);
```

I am just outputting everything to the console to see if I can get the values from the sun element but I cannot get the values from it. Once I get the values I will try and display them into my html. 
I have been stuck on this for a while, Ive read and tried many different things and cannot get passed what I have, and everything comes back as undefined or error... Anyone help would be great, thx

Answer (score 0):

Use getAttribute and reference it by the name

```js
// just getting the xml into an object
var txt = `
  <current>
    <city id="2343" name="Edmonton">
      <coord lon="444" lat="54"></coord>
      <country>CA</country>
      <sun rise="2020-03-01t02:07:33" set="2020-03-01t07:33"></sun>
    </city>
  </current>`
var parser = new DOMParser();
var weatherXML = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");

// grab the first city
var city = weatherXML.getElementsByTagName("city")[0]
// grab the sun (hot!)
var sun = city.getElementsByTagName("sun")[0]

// read the attributes
console.log('rise:', sun.getAttribute('rise'))
console.log('set:', sun.getAttribute('set'))
```

Comment: Thanks but I cant get your code to work for mine, I tried taking my weatherXML and use it in place of your txt.

Comment: I am not sure what is different that would be causing it not to work. The XML you gave as the sample has a two major typos in it which cause it not to work. I fixed those in my code. Hopefully they are not in the actual response from the server.